# system reliability, probabilities of rocket launch suspended

Tags: probability, reliability

A rocket has 3 computers (a,b,c). If a fails than b will take over and so on. Each computer has 0.01 failure rate. These 3 computers are linked to an expensive sensor. If this sensor fails than all 3 computers will fail, this sensor has a failure rate of 10^-6. What are the chances the rocket launch has to be suspended?

So i tried solving this by using the formulas of system reliability. i put the computers in a parrel and linked them in series to the sensor.

I came up with the following formula P(s) = 1-(1-10^-6)*(1-0.01^3) = 0.000002

I have a feeling my answer is wrong though. Could anyone help me confirm this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The question isn't quite clear. If a computer fails because the sensor fails, does that count towards the computer's failure rate? Or is this a different type of "failure" than is counted by the failure rate? Also, are the four failure events independent?

Comment: The sensor failure is independant of the computer's failure rate . and im not sure what u mean with the second question. I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: I mean: There are four possible failure events (three for the computers and one for the sensor). In reality, these will be correlated; e.g., if a computer fails due to overheating, it's more likely that another computer also fails due to overheating. You haven't specified a joint probability distribution, so it sounds like you're assuming that these events are all independent; I was just checking whether this is the intended interpretation of the question.

Comment: Yes they are all independent, the only common thing they have is that if the sensor fails than they all fail. But they fail rate of that sensor is independent of the fail rate of the computers. So what i mean is even if the sensor wasnt there, the fail rate of the computers would stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer looks correct.  My approach (which I think is the same as yours) would be:

- (ignoring the sensor) what is the probability a particular computer fails?

  - $0.01$
- (ignoring the sensor) what is the probability all three computers fail?

  - $0.01^3 = 0.000001$ by independence
- (ignoring the sensor) what is the probability at least one of the three computers does not fail?

  - $1- 0.000001=0.999999$
- what is the probability the sensor does not fail?

  - $1- 0.000001=0.999999$
- what is the probability the sensor does not fail and (ignoring the sensor) at least one of the three computers does not fail?

  - $0.999999 \times 0.999999 = 0.999998000001$ by independence
- what is the probability either the sensor fails or all three computers fails?

  - $1- 0.999998000001 = 0.000001999999$ which is essentially your $0.000002$

joriki's questions in the comments are about checking whether *ignoring the sensor* and *independence* are correct interpretations of the question

Comment: Thanks alot! I thought i would be wrong because in reality rocket launches get suspended way more often than 0.000002. I suppose this doesn't take into account other things that could go wrong.